# Cannot upload file using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, upload

I have cgi for upload files, when I use the `<form>` to upload files, it works great, but it doesn't work if I use ajax to send data......

The form is like this:

```
<form id="confUpdate" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.cgi">
    <input id='upLoad' type='file' name="file">
    <input id='btnUpload' type="submit" name="send" value="Upload">
</form>
```

It can work if I  just let the button type='submit'.

When I change the type of button 'submit' to 'button', and try javascript:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var upfile=document.getElementById("upLoad");
    var upform=document.getElementById("confUpdate");
    var btnUpload=document.getElementById("btnUpload");
    var info=document.getElementById("InfoText");
    var xhr;
    btnUpload.onclick=function(){
        var file=upfile.files;
        var formData=new FormData();
        if(file[0].name.split(".")[1]!="bin"){
            info.innerHTML="The file should be .bin file.";
        }else{
            info.innerHTML="";
            formData.append("file",file[0],file[0].name);
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        try{
            xhr.open('POST', 'upload.cgi', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type","multipart/form-data");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = onReceive;
            xhr.send(formData);
        }catch(e){
            xhr.abort();
        }
    }

    function onReceive(){
        var xml;
        var elem;
        if(xhr.readyState==4){
            if(xhr.status==200){
                xml=xhr.responseText;
                info.innerHTML="Uploaded:"+xml;
            }else{
                info.innerHTML="Something is error.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After I clicking the button, the debug text is show 'Uploaded:', means it's send the file data, but the xml( content of the respond by server side) is empty.

I'm not sure it's my server side error or my javascript side error?

I guess the file should be name='file'.

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Where is your server side code? Also, add logging to your server side code to ensure that everything is working as expected.

Comment: Either set `content-type` to null or just don't set the request header.

Comment: Does your browser support ajax file sending?

Comment: Have you looked at the Net tag in you browser's developer tools to see what the data structure being sent was?

Comment: Sorry for replying too late, I'm busy last weekend for my mom in hospital :(

@Ankit, my server side code is in the same directory as my local side web page( I use bash shell to write the html content)
@Rahil Wazir, it's a ajax for file upload, and I tried not to set the request header, and still doesn't work :(
@maxim.tkachenko, I use crome and firefox, and it can use ajax without situation of file uploading.
@Quentin, I use firefox to debug, and the sending just as same as I use `<form>` to submit data.
Hope you can help me further more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what's wrong!

I check the api of the upload, and found that I need to send the name of the button, too!

So the ajax is now:

```
            var upfile=document.getElementById("upfile");
            var upform=document.getElementById("upform");
            var btnUpload=document.getElementById("btnUpload");
            var info=document.getElementById("InfoText");
            var xhr;

            upform.onsubmit = function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                info.innerHTML="";

                var files=upfile.files;
                var formData=new FormData();
                if(files[0].name.split(".")[1]!="bin"){
                    info.innerHTML="The file should be .bin file.";
                }else{
                    info.innerHTML="Uploading, please wait.";
                    formData.append("file",files[0],files[0].name);
                    formData.append("send","Send");

                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }else{
                        xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    try{
                        xhr.open('POST', 'upload.cgi', true);
                        //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
                        xhr.onreadystatechange = onReceive;
                        xhr.send(formData);
                    }catch(e){
                        xhr.abort();
                    }
                }
            }

            function onReceive(){
                var xml;
                var elem;
                if(xhr.readyState==4){
                    if(xhr.status==200){
                        xml=xhr.responseText;
                        info.innerHTML="Uploaded:"+xml;
                    }else{
                        info.innerHTML="Something is error.";
                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm so foolish~ Who knows that the name of button is important when I upload a file?

And thanks to all for giving me any advices!