# Uploading files to a user upon WordPress registration with AJAX and ACF

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, file-upload, registration

So I'm trying to create a custom registration form where users can also upload files (ie. a Resume) by using AJAX and Modal.

I found this tutorial that will let me do that, but the problem is, I'm not sure how I can upload the files that will also connect to ACF.

http://fellowtuts.com/wordpress/wordpress-ajax-login-and-register-without-a-plugin/

I was able to do this with the help of this discussion, but it only works if I'm not using AJAX:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282586/acf-upload-image-in-front-end-with-custom-form/283079#283079

Can anyone help me out? Thank you!

Note: I deleted some stuff that may not be related to my question, so feel free to ask me if there is anything missing. Here's my code:

```
<form id="student_register" class="ajax-auth"  action="register" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

    <p class="status"></p>

    <?php wp_nonce_field('stud-ajax-register-nonce', 'stud_signonsecurity'); ?>
        <label for="stud_email">School Email*</label>
        <input id="stud_email" type="text" class="required email" name="stud_email" placeholder="Enter school email address">

        <label for="stud_signonpassword">Password*</label>
        <input id="stud_signonpassword" type="password" class="required" name="stud_signonpassword">

        <label for="uploadResume" class="custom-file-upload">Upload Your Resume
        </label>
        <input type="file" id="uploadResume" class="uploadResume" name="uploadResume" accept=".doc, .docx,.pdf" style="display:none;" value="">
    </div>
    <input class="submit_button green-btn green-btn--fullWidth" type="submit" value="Submit Registration">
</form>
```

My jQuery File called ajax-auth-script.js

```
 //jQuery
    // Perform AJAX login/register on form submit
    $('form#student_register').on('submit', function (e) {

        if (!$(this).valid()) return false;
        $('p.status', this).show().text(ajax_auth_object.loadingmessage);

            action = 'ajaxregisterstudent';
            security = $('#stud_signonsecurity').val();
            resume = $('#uploadResume').val();
            password = $('#stud_signonpassword').val();
            email = $('#stud_email').val();

        ctrl = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_auth_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action': action,
                'password': password,
                'email': email,
                'security': security,
                'resume': resume,

            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('p.status', ctrl).text(data.message);
                if (data.loggedin == true) {
                    document.location.href = ajax_auth_object.redirecturl;
                } 
            },
            error: function() {
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

My function in functions.php:

```
function ajax_auth_init(){

    wp_register_script('ajax-auth-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/ajax-auth-script.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-auth-script');

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-auth-script', 'ajax_auth_object', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'redirecturl' => site_url() . "/wp-admin/", //redirect_login_page() <-- when user logs in, it will go to the wp-admin and then this function will check to see where they should go
        'loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')
    ));

    // Enable the student user with no privileges to run ajax_register() in AJAX
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxregisterstudent', 'ajax_register_student' );
}

// Execute the action only if the user isn't logged in
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    add_action('init', 'ajax_auth_init');
}


function ajax_register_student(){

    // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
    check_ajax_referer( 'stud-ajax-register-nonce', 'security' );

    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $resume = $_POST["resume"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $verify = $_POST["verify"];

    $info = array(
          'user_pass'   =>  $password,
          'user_login'  =>  $email,
          'user_email'  =>  $email,
          'user_nicename'  =>   $email,
      );
    // Register the user
    $user_register = wp_insert_user( $info );

        //assign media to user
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

        // Let WordPress handle the upload.
        $img_id = media_handle_upload( 'resume', 0 );

        if ( !is_wp_error( $img_id ) ) {
            //assign author to media
            $arg = array(
                'ID' => $img_id,
                'post_author' => $user_register,
            );
            wp_update_post( $arg );
            //assign media to author
            update_user_meta( $user_register, 'qd_resume', $img_id );
        }

    if ( is_wp_error($user_register) ){
        $error  = $user_register->get_error_codes() ;

        // echo $user_register->get_error_message();
        if(in_array('empty_user_login', $error))
            echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__($user_register->get_error_message('empty_user_login'))));
        elseif(in_array('existing_user_login',$error))
            echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('This username is already registered.')));
        elseif(in_array('existing_user_email',$error))
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('This email address is already registered.')));
    }
    else {
      auth_user_login($info['user_login'], $info['user_pass'], 'Registration');
    }

    die();
}
```

If I comment out the condition that if there is no error in grabbing the $img_id, my meta_value for the qd_resume meta_key has this error, and I couldn't understand why it wouldn't grab the file

> O:8:"WP_Error":4:{s:6:"errors";a:1:{s:12:"upload_error";a:1:{i:0;s:212:"File
>   is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could
>   also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by
>   post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in
>   php.ini.";}}s:10:"error_data";a:0:{}s:2:"ID";i:0;s:6:"filter";s:3:"raw";}

```
/*************************************************
AUTHORIZE LOGIN
**************************************************/
function auth_user_login($user_login, $password, $login)
{
    $info = array();
    $info['user_login'] = $user_login;
    $info['user_password'] = $password;
    $info['remember'] = true;

    $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
    } else {
        wp_set_current_user($user_signon->ID); 
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__($login.' successful, redirecting...')));
    }

    die();
}

/***********************************************************************************
// Deal with images uploaded from the front-end while allowing ACF to do it's thing
**************************************************************************************/
function my_acf_pre_save_post($user_register) {

    if ( !function_exists('wp_handle_upload') ) {
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    }

    // Move file to media library
    // $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES['uploadResume'], array('test_form' => false) );
    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES['resume'], array('test_form' => false) );

    // If move was successful, insert WordPress attachment
    if ( $movefile && !isset($movefile['error']) ) {
        $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $attachment = array(
            'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($movefile['file']),
            'post_mime_type' => $movefile['type'],
            'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', ”, basename($movefile['file']) ),
            'post_content' => ”,
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $movefile['file']);

        // Assign the file as the featured image
        // set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attach_id);
        // update_field('uploadResume', $attach_id, $post_id);

        update_user_meta( $user_register, 'qd_resume', $attach_id );

    }

    return $user_register;

}

add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'my_acf_pre_save_post');
```

Comment: [ May help you ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24857153/6158032)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than offering a readymade solution, I would provide you steps to submit file along with AJAX request.

- You have already included file input in the registration form.
- You require FormData object instead of key/value object to pass the file in AJAX request.
- At the server, you can save the file using either WordPress APIs (wp_handle_upload/media_handle_upload) or plain PHP.

So basically you need to append the FormData to the object. This script below might help you.

```
var uploadResume = document.getElementById('uploadResume');

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('resume ', uploadResume.files[0]);
formdata.append('action', 'ajaxregisterstudent');
//Append security, password, email etc.

//...
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formdata,
    success: ...
```

I'm not sure what/how are you implementing ACF in the server-side code. However, hope this will help you to get in the right direction.

Ref.:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects
https://www.ibenic.com/wordpress-file-upload-with-ajax/

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the Fellow Tuts blog post mentioned here.

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you for the guidance! ^_^

Comment: You can accept the answer to help others understand what is needed to submit files to WordPress AJAX requests.